# iOS 8: NSDictionary 0 key/value pairs

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsdictionary, ios8

Believe me or not, it's the real case. I'm creating a simple `NSDictionary` in my app and it was working fine. Today I installed `Xcode 6 beta` and try to run my app with iOS 8. `NSDictionary` returns `0 key/value pairs` while I can see same dictionary works fine in iOS 6 and in iOS 7. Here is the code of that dictionary,

```
NSDictionary *croppedPhoto = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:myImageView.image,@"original",imageView.image,@"cropped", nil];
```

**NOTE:** `myImageView` and `imageView` both are `UIImageView` and I can see the image there in debug mode.
I don't know if something changed in `iOS 8` regarding `NSDictionary`. Appreciate any kind of help in advance. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to this code and see what happens...

```
NSDictionary *croppedPhoto = @{
    @"original" : myImageView.image,
    @"cropped"  : imageView.image
};
```

You should be using this format anyway. It has been around for 2 years now.

Also, it includes run time validation that all the objects are not nil.

If `myImageView.image` is nil then your code will return a dictionary with no keys or objects, this modern syntax will crash showing you that it is nil.

Comment: Yes, `myImageView.image` was nil in my case. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @iEngineer ok. Now do this... In Xcode. Go to Edit - Refactor - Convert to Modern Objective-C syntax. This will update all your code to use the updated syntax like this. It will make it more readable and help you out like this.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you use modern syntax?

```
NSDictionary *croppedPhoto = @{
    @"original": myImageView.image,
    @"cropped":  imageView.image
}
```

(Which is, admit it, much more readable).

Comment: crashed with bill exception for object[0];